# React Native Navigation const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am learning `react-native` navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ . I see in examples there

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I could not understand what exactly this line of code is for `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: It's called destructuring assignment. It's the same thing as `const navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate`.

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

syntax has nothing to do with React Native 
it is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in es6 / es2015

`const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

is equivilent to with exception to var and const .

`var navigate  = this.props.navigation.navigate`

the example without Destructuring should look like this

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where and how it is being used in my program ? how it works ?

Comment: it is basically pulling the `navigate` method directly from `this.props.navigate` and assigning it to the variable `navigate` .

Comment: so here `onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}` Is it referencing  `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: yes : namely `onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat') }` the exact same thing .

Comment: `this.props.navigation` what I understood from this is that `navigation` is the props. I have a question it's property of which component ?

Comment: it was passed to `HomeScreen` from the parent component  , 
parent could be rendering `HomeScreen` as follows , 
`<HomeScreen navigation={/* obj to pass *?} />`

Comment: `const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);` it is rendering HomeScreen but here nothing is being passed.

Comment: docs :   
NOTE: The `navigation` prop is passed down to every navigation-aware component including navigators. The big exception is that a navigator's `navigation` prop may not have the helper functions (`navigate`, `goBack`, etc); it may only have `state` and `dispatch`. In order to `navigate` using the navigator's `navigation` prop, you will have to `dispatch` using an action creator.

Answer (score 1):

Include on your ServiceAction the `this.props.navigation` something like this:

```
<HomeScreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

because the `props.navigation` are by default on your parent component

and on HomeScreen component you will access to navition like:

```
..
goToSignUp() {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
}
..
```

For me also was confusing before. Cheers!